# On-demand Windows-based gitlab-ci-runner

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm experimenting with automated builds for a Windows app. I want to put my windows CI runner on AWS. I'd also like for this machine to not be up 24/7 because other than running builds it does nothing else.

What I'm trying to accomplish is have the CI workflow make an API call to start up the EC2 instance, wait for it to come alive and then have the gitlab-ci-runner inside the windows instance do its thing.

Is this something gitlab can do out of the box? Or do I need an intermediary ci-runner that is always active to manage the state of the windows instance?